# For Loop and indexing

Tags: matlab

Following is my code :

```
function marks(my_numbers)
handle = zeros(5,1)
x = 10 ;
y = 10:20:100 ;
for i = 1
    for j = 1:5 ;
        handle(j,i) = rectangle('position',[x(i),y(j),20 10],'facecolor','r') 
    end
end
end
```

now lets say input argument    my_numbers = 2
so i have written the code :

```
set(handle(j(my_numbers),1),'facecolor','g')
```

With this command, rectangle with lower left corner at (30,10) should have turned green. But MATLAB gives an error of index exceeds matrix dimensions

Comment: Your index i is sort of pointless - fix it as 1. x = 10 so why you need to do x(i)? Please print the exact error message from the console. Also, the colours probably should be 20, 10 not 20 10.

Answer (score 1):

This is more an illustrated comment than an answer, but as @hagubear mentioned your `i` index is pointless so you could remove it altogether.

Using `set(handle(my_numbers,1),'facecolor','g')` will remove the error, because you were trying to access `handles(j(2),1)` and that was not possible because `j` is a scalar.

Anyhow using this line after your plot works fine:

```
set(handle(my_numbers,1),'facecolor','g')
```

According to your comment below, here is a way to call the function multiple times and add green rectangles as you go along. There are 2 files for the purpose of demonstration, the function per se and a script to call the function multiple times and generate an animated gif:

1) The function:

```
function marks(my_numbers)

%// Get green and red rectangles to access their properties.
GreenRect = findobj('Type','rectangle','FaceColor','g');
RedRect = findobj('Type','rectangle');

%// If 1st call to the function, create your plot
if isempty(RedRect)

    handle = zeros(5,1);

    x = 10 ;
    y = 10:20:100 ;

    for j = 1:5 ;
        handle(j) = rectangle('position',[x,y(j),20 10],'facecolor','r');
    end

    set(handle(my_numbers,1),'facecolor','g')
%// If not 1st call, fetch existing green rectangles and color them green. Then color the appropriate rectangle given by my_numbers.    
else
    RedRect = flipud(RedRect); %// Flip them to maintain correct order
    if numel(GreenRect) > 0
        hold on
        for k = numel(GreenRect)
            set(GreenRect(k),'facecolor','g')
            set(RedRect(my_numbers,1),'facecolor','g')
        end
    end

end
```

2) The script:

```
clear
clc

%// Shuffle order for appearance of green rectangles.
iter = randperm(5);

filename = 'MyGifFile.gif';
for k = iter

    marks(k)

    pause(1)

    frame = getframe(1);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if k == iter(1)
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');
    end

end
```

Here is the animated gif of the output:

[image]

Comment: yes , however, I also want that when this function is called again with input argument my_numbers = 3, previous one should stay green instead of turning red.

Comment: Alright I edit my answer I think that's what you want. Be sure to open the animated gif!

Comment: Great I found how to show animated gif! Is this what you wanted?